# Android: uploading big file causes out of memory exception

Tags: android, http-post, out-of-memory

I develope an app, where you can record audio and then you can upload it to a server. My problem is, when I am trying to upload a big audio file I got "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" exception. I make a FileInputStream from the file, and try to send it via HTTP POST. Do you have any idea how can I upload bigger file? And I don't understand why it mentions bitmap size, as I see, it has nothing to do with bitmaps.